# ERROR: Is the robot out of the map?

Tags: ros, navigation, nav2d, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I use nav2d in a real robot with kinect.
But when I call /StartMapping, there is an error:

> ERROR: Is the robot out of the map?

Here is a print screen of the costmap and my costmap.yaml.

Any ideas about what's wrong?
[print screen http://s32.postimg.org/w6ru7o1cl/Screenshot_from_2016_05_16_18_48_49.png](http://s32.postimg.org/w6ru7o1cl/Screenshot_from_2016_05_16_18_48_49.png)

(when i had a similar problem with navigation_stack I remember that I moved the origin_x and origin_y of the costmap, but I think nav2d does not have such parameters)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234420/error:-is-the-robot-out-of-the-map?/) by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-05-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on 2016-05-17**:
Ok I fixed it, the problem was I computed and published wrong odometry.

**Comment by [saba.k](https://answers.ros.org/users/29739/saba.k/) on 2017-04-20**:
Hi @MariaKrgr . How did you solve your problem? What exactly did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem is not related to the (local) costmap, but to the path planner that uses the global map generated by the mapper. Please check the generated map and the robot's position within this map.

(The nav2d mapper doesn't have an origin_x/y map parameter, because it applies a graph based approach that can grow the map dynamically as the robot moves.)

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on 2016-05-17**:
I found out that I have wrong odometry published, so you think that this should be the problem?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-05-17**:
This is possible, as both the local costmap and the mapper depend on the odometry.

**Comment by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on 2016-05-17**:
I posted a new question (better clarified) here. If you have the time and kindness take a look.
http://answers.ros.org/question/234488/cannot-fix-mapping-in-real-robot/